# How to create a sitemap for a forum

Tags: seo, sitemap

How would you create a sitemap for a forum where pages are created every hour, because on daily basis approximately 5-10 new pages are created.

Should you be adding all of them to the sitemap and update it everyday? Doesn't sound correct.

Comment: Your forum web application should do this for you.

Comment: I just gave an example of forum. but it is infact a custom app creating around 5-10 pages per day.

Comment: Well, you could ignore the fact you don't have a sitemap. A sitemap only helps search engines confirm what its crawled. So if your site crawls ok its not a problem.

Comment: The reason i want to setup a sitemap is because i want to suggest the priority and frequency of page crawl

Comment: Worth nothing that priority and frequency isn't a sure thing, Google can work out roughly how often your site updates without and by setting a priority and freq in the site map doesn't mean Google will follow these rules.  just saying...

Comment: I agree, but as a best practice i feel it is worth telling google to start with.

Answer (score -1):

A sitemap is not for pages that are constantly changing. It's for showing the structure of a site, not new content of each page. If you are constantly adding and changing that many pages a day, which sounds strange to me, that is what a RSS or Atom feed can be used for. Google, at least, looks for those to indicate changes within pages that are already listed in the sitemap.

Comment: i don't think it is strange. May be i did no explain it properly. Let us take an example of this site stackexchange. It has tons of pages created every day. How do they maintain the sitemap.

Comment: There knowledgeable enough to make an app which does it for them after-all they created this great engine. If you made your forum then simply make an app yourself... otherwise use a CMS Forum, I'm not sure what your expecting as an answer...

Comment: I think you mis-read the question Rob, he said pages are created, not just the content changing.

Comment: My Main reason for creating sitemap is recommending priority for specific pages.